# I use sqlcipher, after updating the app its throwing the error "File is not a database"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlcipher

The only thing that changed before and after updation is header file
I changed from  "#import sqlite3.h " to  "#import SqlCipher/sqlite3.h"and it stopped recognising the older database after the update.

Comment: Delete the old app, compile again with SqlCipher, and now should work.

Comment: I dont wana delete, since it removes my database too....I want to use my older files

Comment: I see. Then you can dump your database to an sql text file and import it on the Build Phase-Run script.

Comment: Did you mean sqlite3_export ?

Comment: No. you can just open Terminal and do: sqlite3 myDatabase.db; .output mysql.txt .dump. See: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/ . Once you have the file you can put on Xcode (Buidl Pahse -Run script). This way you will have your old database but now encripted.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I solved it using the same procedure but using sqlcipher's sqlite3_export.